# copy paste in iterm, vim

Tags: macos, vim, copy-paste, tmux, iterm2

I use iterm in Mac as my command line terminal. In iterm I use tmux as the terminal manager. When I open my code files in Vim copying has become painful in this. To copy text in vim I need to hold "option" key and then select the text. When holding option there are multiple issues:
1) I am unable to scroll while in select mode
2) When I split my terminal into 2 panes, select using option copies across panes making it tough.

I am not sure about the reason for this issue and where to find a workaround. Could anyone help me with it?

Comment: Try to use `macvim` for GUI, and `macvim -v` for CLI instead of `vim` (`brew install vim --override-system-vi`). Then put `set clipboard=unnamed` into the vim configuration file, and use the normal copying and pasting features (see `:help copy-move`)

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov: Good addendum to my answer - it is probable that clipboard support is not baked into the default Vim. However, once you override system Vim, `vim` in terminal gives you terminal MacVim; not sure what `macvim -v` is, as `macvim` is not an existent executable.

Answer (score 11):

You cannot depend on iTerm's clipboard support because it will not know anything about Vim's or tmux's splits. Use native Vim copy instead.

```
:help v
:help V
:help y
:help d
:help "*
:help clipboard
```

So e.g. in order to copy two lines, you can do `"*2yy` (to clipboard register, two line yank); or you can mark something using visual mode, then just `"*y` (to clipboard register, yank). If you want the clipboard register to be always automatically used unless another register is specified, you can add the following to your `.vimrc`:

```
set clipboard+=unnamed
```

Then a simple `2yy` will copy two lines, and you can just paste it in iTerm or any other application.

Comment: There must be another step to get this to work in iTerm 2 because neither `"*yy` nor the `set clipboard` command will let me copy/paste from the clipboard in iTerm2 with Mac OS High Sierra.

Comment: @LondonRob: Do you have clipboard support in your Vim? (`:version`, then look for `+clipboard` or `-clipboard`). OSX default Vim doesn't have it compiled in, MacVim does, NeoVim does.

Comment: Yes! This was my problem. I'll try and work out how to get these in terminal Vim. Thanks!

Comment: @LondonRob NeoVim and MacVim also are “terminal Vim”. MacVim _also_ has the GUI mode. But you can’t get this in default Vim. Best you can do in default Vim is piping into `pbcopy`.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks @Amadan, this fixed my problem!